# WP File manager not supported

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to install the WP filemanager plugin to edit some source files, but i am getting this error that the plugin "is not supported." Can anyone explain why this may be, is there a plugin conflict or something similar? Please let me know as filezilla was not working so I resorted to a plugin instead. It says that it is supported on my version of wordpress as well.

[Wordpress screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq83S.png)

Comment: If _"filezilla was not working"_, that sounds like you probably have a problem with file access rights. Possible, that the plugin determines that it is "not supported" because it also has trouble accessing files. You should really rather investigate the reason why you have problems accessing your files via FTP, than try to find plugins that help work around the issue somehow.

Comment: yea i figured it out, i was doing a website for a friend and apparently they r using wordpress.com not .org so that is why

Answer (score 0):

You can Try :

- I have tested, deactivated all the plugins, locally living only
  wp-file-manager active, and then it worked.
- I started activating one by one each plugin and it stopped working when I activated Wordfence Security.

Which makes me think that there is something unsecure on wp-file-manager.